# How to convert TSV data to JSON Object in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, csv, json-arrayagg

TSV Data :
[image]

```
Required OutPut :
[{
candidates: {
id:"agent_4",
text = "can i get a confirmation code",
count = 2},
{
id:"agent_11",
text = "text_2",
count =3},
}]
```

I got the similar question for JQ, but how can I achieve this in java? [Convert TSV file to multiple JSON arrays with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133046/convert-tsv-file-to-multiple-json-arrays-with-jq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load file by [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and use [JsonArray](https://JsonArray) to format your Json output

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.tsv"));

    String[] fieldNames = reader.readLine().split("\t");

   
    List<JSONObject> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    // Read tsv file line by line
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        
        String[] fields = line.split("\t");

        JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
            row.put(fieldNames[i], fields[i]);
        }
        rows.add(row);
    }

    reader.close();

    // Convert the list of rows to a JSON array
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(rows);
```