# rdd.zipWithIndex() throwing IllegalArgumentException on very large data set

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, rdd, azure-databricks

I'm running a python notebook in Azure Databricks.  I am getting an IllegalArgumentException error when trying to add a line number with rdd.zipWithIndex().  The file is 2.72 GB and 1238951 lines (I think, text editor acts wonky with this big of a file).  It ran for over 4 hours before it failed. I'm wondering if we are reaching some sort of size limit since the Exception is IllegalArgumentException.  I'd like to know how to prevent this exception, and/or any way to make it faster. I was thinking I may have to break it down into smaller files. Any help is appreciated.

Code snippet

```
runKey = "cca2e0f0-bec0-408a-a5cb-341d26e8b7e0" # this is new id for every file
filePath = "/mnt/my_file_path/my_file.txt"
rdd = sc.textFile(filePath)
rdd = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda line: "{}{}{}{}{}".format(str(runKey), delimiter, str(line[1]+1), delimiter, line[0]))
```

Output from error

```
  File "<command-3893172145851236>", line 26, in OpenFileRDD
    rdd = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda line: "{}{}{}{}{}".format(str(runKey), delimiter, str(line[1]+1), delimiter, line[0]))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2524, in zipWithIndex
    nums = self.mapPartitions(lambda it: [sum(1 for i in it)]).collect()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 967, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 1234573.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 1234573.0 (TID 46064376) (10.0.2.5 executor 5455): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:334)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:280)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$textFile$2(SparkContext.scala:1065)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2241)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:313)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2978)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2925)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2919)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2919)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1357)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1357)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1357)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3127)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3115)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1069)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6189.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:334)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:280)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$textFile$2(SparkContext.scala:1065)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2241)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:313)
```

Comment: Did you try to break the file into smaller pieces and see if it works? You could try out something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249516/split-text-file-into-smaller-multiple-text-file-using-command-line first and then run your Spark job again

Comment: Can you provide sample content of the file?

Comment: @JayashankarGS, I cannot, because it's private healthcare data.  The longest line in the file is 965 characters and the average is about 918 characters.

Comment: @JayashankarGS Thanks for your response.  The last line of the file was corrupted!! UGH!  I could not see until I opened it in Ultra Edit, which displayed a bunch of squares at the end of the last line.  My other text editors could not open it or would not show the squares.  The last valid character in ultra edit was also the last valid character I was able to read with code...  after I could see it in Ultra Edit and I wrote a function to read it character by character.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with more than `965` characters in the single line,
and it worked fine.
That is 15295 characters in a single line.

[image]

So, this error occurs when string object consists more than
the max limit. That is 2^31 - 1.
There can be more number of characters in a single line than this max limit.
Check it once properly.

So, I created file having single line of length 2^31-1,
and tried your code it took 1.2hr and given kernal restart error.

I would suggest split the lines having more length and add your information.

```
with  open("/dbfs/output.txt", 'r') as file_data:
    for line in file_data:
        print(f"before split {len(line)}")
        data = line.split("0")
        print(f"After split {len(data)}")
```

Here, I used `0` as split condition in your case use which split the lines meaningfully
to your requirement.

[image]

This is just a single line data in text file.
Check in your file how large the string is, or you can just split the line according to the record size as below.

```
charset = "UTF-8"
recordSize = 500
df = sc.binaryRecords("dbfs:/output.txt", recordSize).map(lambda record: (str(record, charset),)).toDF(schema=["value"])
```

[image]