# Vbscript strip text file by filesize without losing contents of last line

Tags: vbscript

I have the following Vbscript code which currently splits a large text file into smaller files by filesize argument in MB:

```
Sub Split
  Dim iFile, oFile, iStream, Data
  Dim Ext, e, offset, length, NewName
  
  Info (" ==> Splitting " & sFile & " by " & Size & "B files and saving to " & dPath)
  
  if not oFSO.FileExists(sFile) then Error _
  ("Cannot locate the file """ & sFile & """")
  Set iFile = oFSO.GetFile(sFile)
  
  On Error Resume Next
  Set iStream = iFile.OpenAsTextStream(1)

  if err.number > 0 then Error("Cannot open the file """ & sFile _
  & """" & LF & Err.Description)

  On Error Goto 0
  Data = iStream.Read(iFile.Size)
  iStream.close
  
  Ext = 0
  offset = 1
  
  Do
    Ext = Right("00" & Ext + 1, 3)
    if ext > "999" then Error ("Too many files - maximum is 999!")
    
    NewName = dPath & prefix & datetype & suffix & "_" & Ext & ".txt"
    Info "Writing """ & NewName & """"

    On Error Resume Next
  
    ' ---> Write file
    Set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(NewName, 2)

    if err.number > 0 then Error("Cannot open the file """ _
    & NewName & """" & LF & Err.Description)
    On Error Goto 0
    
    length = Size
    If length > Len(data)+1 - offset Then length = Len(data) + 1 - offset
    
    oFile.Write Mid(Data, offset, length)
    offset = offset + length
    oFile.Close
  Loop Until offset >= Len(data)

End Sub
```

The above code works however, when the large file is split into smaller files it will split contents of the final line for each file too but I would like to retain all contents on the line and split at the end of the line as well as by current filesize function I have.

For example end of line (last line in smaller files) being as follows:

This is a test

The last line stored each each file my be cut and can look like the following:

This is a te

Is it possible to retain all contents on the line and split at the end of the line as well as by current filesize, if so how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You might be reinventing the wheel. There are many file splitting tools available, most of which will run much faster than VBS code. Some are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249516/split-text-file-into-smaller-multiple-text-file-using-command-line)

Comment: @LesFerch Yes am aware of other languages to use, but its a requirement to get it done in vbs unfortunately

Comment: Rather then just posting existing code to be altered, what attempt have you made to solve the problem and what specific issue did you face? At the moment this is just a code writing request which is not what [so] is for.

Comment: @LesFerch statements like "challenge accepted" just encourage more code request questions which is not what [so] is there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the file by size, and only split on line ends, can be achieved by shifting the end point of each chunk to the next CRLF. Here's your Split Sub with that enhancement.

```
Sub Split
  Dim iFile, oFile, iStream, Data, TotalSize
  Dim Ext, e, offset, length, NewName
  
  Info (" ==> Splitting " & sFile & " by " & Size & "B files and saving to " & dPath)
  
  if not oFSO.FileExists(sFile) then Error _
  ("Cannot locate the file """ & sFile & """")
  Set iFile = oFSO.GetFile(sFile)
  
  On Error Resume Next
  Set iStream = iFile.OpenAsTextStream(1)

  if err.number > 0 then Error("Cannot open the file """ & sFile _
  & """" & LF & Err.Description)

  On Error Goto 0
  Data = iStream.Read(iFile.Size)
  iStream.close
  TotalSize = Len(Data)
  
  Ext = 0
  offset = 1
  
  Do
    Ext = Right("00" & Ext + 1, 3)
    if ext > "999" then Error ("Too many files - maximum is 999!")
    
    NewName = dPath & prefix & datetype & suffix & "_" & Ext & ".txt"
    Info "Writing """ & NewName & """"

    On Error Resume Next
  
    ' ---> Write file
    Set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(NewName, 2)

    if err.number > 0 then Error("Cannot open the file """ _
    & NewName & """" & LF & Err.Description)
    On Error Goto 0
    
    length = Size
    If length > TotalSize+1 - offset Then length = TotalSize + 1 - offset

    'Shift the end point to the next CRLF
    Do While Mid(Data, offset+length, 2)<>VBCRLF And offset+length<TotalSize
      length = length + 1
    Loop
    If Mid(Data, offset+length, 2)=VBCRLF Then length = length + 2
    
    oFile.Write Mid(Data, offset, length)
    offset = offset + length
    oFile.Close
  Loop Until offset >= TotalSize

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! - Thank you

Comment: Ofc it does, you've just had a free code writing service!

Comment: @user692942 Yeah well I've also contributed my original code for others to use and another user was kind enough to update my code with extra functionality to achieve what I wanted (my previous attempts were well off as I just had no idea how to do this) - FYI my original function can still work fine for others as well as updated version!

Comment: If you wrote the "original code" the change you required would have been a minor change to implement. The fact you were asking for this change with the code you provided is a massive red flag.