# Large csv impossible to handle

Tags: csv, python-3.x, opencsv

I am trying to access a 2.2 GB csv file.  Excel and R are useless for this. SAS could have worked, but it seems that the file is corrupted and SAS cannot handle that. I am trying to do something with Python, but no luck so far.  Any advice would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the CSV with Python or just for recommendations on any editor that can handle huge CSV files?

Comment: This isn't very specific; it's not clear what you want to do with the file (the docs for the csv module explain how to read the rows, so it must be something more complicated), or what's causing you problems at the moment.

Comment: I'll take whatever you have, I'm getting desperate by now, have been trying this for days, thanks.

Comment: This solution may help : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602869/batch-file-to-split-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for accessing the file: vim and gvim have large file plugins, depending on your OS.