# Split multiple CSV files in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-console

I have used this script found here on SO:

[Batch file to split .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602869/batch-file-to-split-csv-file)

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set limit=50
set file=export.csv
set lineCounter=1
set filenameCounter=1

set name=
set extension=
for %%a in (%file%) do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "extension=%%~xa"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    set splitFile=!name!-part!filenameCounter!!extension!
    if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
        set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1
        set lineCounter=1
        echo Created !splitFile!.
    )
    echo %%a>> !splitFile!

    set /a lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1
)
```

This splits one file into several smaller files (50 lines each).I would like to get it to split all the files in a specific/current directory.

Comment: Put another `for` loop around the existing code.

Comment: @DavidPostill I understand that is what I need. But I am unsure of how to accomplish it within the existing code.

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.csv') do @echo do something with %%f

Comment: @DavidPostill Worked perfectly. Couldn't get it into the "file" variable, but used %%f as you mentioned instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code thanks to @DavidPostill

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.csv') do (

    set limit=100 
    set lineCounter=1
    set filenameCounter=1

    set name=
    set extension=
    for %%a in (%%f) do (
        set "name=%%~na"
        set "extension=%%~xa"
    )

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%%f) do (
        set splitFile=!name!-part!filenameCounter!!extension!"
        if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
            set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1
            set lineCounter=1
            echo Created !splitFile!.
        )
        echo %%a>> !splitFile!

        set /a lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1
    )
)
```