# How to split a file in python

Tags: python, list, file, split

I am trying to split 2 lists, compare them and make a new list without the succesfully compared items in 2 lists.

So lets say 
List_1.txt =

```
Failed = abc
Failed = hfi
Failed = kdi
```

and List_2.txt =

```
1:1:1 - jdsfjdf
2:2:2 - iidf
3:3:3 - abc
6:3:1 - hfi
8:2:1 - kdi
3:1:5 - dua
3:1:2 - dfh
```

I want to compare those lists and make a new_list2 without the list_1 entries.

what I tried was:

```
treinrit = open('List_1', 'r')
lijna = treinrit.readlines()
treinrit.close()

annuleer_treinrit = open('List_2', 'r')
lijnb = annuleer_treinrit.readline()
annuleer_treinrit.close()

lijsta = []
lijstb = []

for a in lijna:
    clean = a.split(' - ')
    print(lijsta)

for b in lijnb:
    lijstb.append(lijnb.split(": "))
```

I just cant get the list to split properly. I only need the last bit of each file to compare but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you checked this page out on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546508/how-can-i-split-a-file-in-python
Hope it helps

Comment: Can you show the desired end results?

Comment: @Hoopdady list_2 without abc, hfi and kdi.

Comment: Without the entire line or just without those strings? Like for `3:3:3 - abc` would you remove the entire line, or just the `abc` so the line would read `3:3:3 - `?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('File1', 'r') as f1:
    f1_stored = []
    for line in f1:
        f1_stored.append(line.split('=')[1].strip())
    with open('File2', 'r') as f2;
        output = []
        for line in f2:
            if not any(failed in line for failed in f1_stored):
                output.append(line)
```

The do what you want with `output`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
bad_stuff = []
with open('List_1', 'r') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        bad_stuff.append(line.split('=')[1].strip())


with open('List_2', 'r') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        if line.split(':')[1].strip() not in bad_stuff:
            print(line)
```

The list `bad_stuff` will have all the elements from the first file after the `=` sign (like `abc`, `hfi` and `kdi`)

Then check the second file, and only print if the part after the `:` sign is not in the list `bad_stuff`

Comment: Thank you this helped me out a lot. What does the [1].strip do exactly?

Comment: `strip()` removes the leading and tailing spaces and newlines. There are commands like `rstrip()` which removes the 'right' so tailing spaces and newlines (Theres also lstrip() as you can guess) .

Comment: Ah tahnks a lot! And the [1]? Does it add a space or something?

Comment: `[1]` is an index. When you call `split()` on a string, it splits the string, and puts it into a `list` In our case the list will have two elements, and we only need the second one. As in most programming languages list indices are numbered from 0. So `list[0]` will give you the first element, `list[1]` will give you the second