# How can i split a huge txt file with the help of python

Tags: python

I have a huge text file(models.txt) and contains lines like given bellow:

```
Model 1
text
text
text
text
END

Model 2
text
text
text
text
END

Model 3
text
text
text
text
END
```

i want to write a function so that it can take "Model 1","Model 2" and "Model 3" as a starting point and "END" as a ending point and write out put file model_1.txt, model_2.txt and Model_3.txt for the respective blocks

as i dont know much programming so i write this

```
a = open('C:/Users/Zebrafish/Desktop/AHR_human_modeling/human/edited/1AHH.B99990013.pdb','r')
lines = a.readlines()

x = 1

for line in lines:
    if 'END' in line:
        PDB_file = open('C:/Users/Zebrafish/Desktop/AHR_human_modeling/human/edited/model_1.pdb','w')
        PDB_file.write(line)
        PDB_file.close()
```

Comment: Sorry but SO is not your personal code factory...show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Update your question instead of posting unformatted code as comment.

Comment: is this duplicate ??   [how-do-i-split-a-huge-text-file-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291740/how-do-i-split-a-huge-text-file-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: If you can read the whole file into memory, it doesn't really count as huge

Comment: @Samuel O'Malley should behalf of me what u tried so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('infile') as f:
    groups = groupby(f, key=str.isspace)
    for k, lines in groups:
        if k:
            continue
        fname = next(lines).strip().lower().replace(' ', '_')+'.txt'
        with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
            outf.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: It splits a huge file

Answer (score 0):

If your file fits into memory, then you could use a regular expression to split the file and then iterate over the matches:

```
with open('models.txt') as handle:
    models = re.findall("Model.*?END", handle.read(), re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    for i, model in enumerate(models):
        with open('model_%s.txt' % i) as output:
            output.write(model)
```

Comment: But what if the letters 'END' occur in one of the text lines?

Comment: @gnibbler, it won't work correct then. Hope OP unmarks this as answer.

Comment: If you're going to read the whole file, I guess you may  get away with `handle.read().split('\n\n')`